# How totest Telegraf [[output.http]]

Tags: http, influxdb, telegraf

I have a sensor system that gathers some data, and sends that data to a Local server, using MQTT. The server listens for that data using Telegraf. I have established an InfluxDB output in Telegraf and it works very well. However, I also want to send the received message to another computer on my local network, using HTTP POST. I have configured this output like this:

```
# # A plugin that can transmit metrics over HTTP
[[outputs.http]]
#   ## URL is the address to send metrics to
url = "http://192.168.0.168:8080/"
#
#   ## Timeout for HTTP message
#   # timeout = "5s"
#
#   ## HTTP method, one of: "POST" or "PUT"
method = "POST"
#namepass = ["*spots*"]
#
#   ## HTTP Basic Auth credentials
#   # username = "username"
#   # password = "pa$$word"
#
#   ## OAuth2 Client Credentials Grant
#   # client_id = "clientid"
#   # client_secret = "secret"
#   # token_url = "https://indentityprovider/oauth2/v1/token"
#   # scopes = ["urn:opc:idm:__myscopes__"]
#
#   ## Optional TLS Config
#   # tls_ca = "/etc/telegraf/ca.pem"
#   # tls_cert = "/etc/telegraf/cert.pem"
#   # tls_key = "/etc/telegraf/key.pem"
#   ## Use TLS but skip chain & host verification
#   # insecure_skip_verify = false
#
#   ## Data format to output.
#   ## Each data format has it's own unique set of configuration options, read
#   ## more about them here:
#   ## https://github.com/influxdata/telegraf/blob/master/docs/DATA_FORMATS_OUTPUT.md
data_format = "influx"
#
#   ## HTTP Content-Encoding for write request body, can be set to "gzip" to
#   ## compress body or "identity" to apply no encoding.
#   # content_encoding = "identity"
#
#   ## Additional HTTP headers
#   # [outputs.http.headers]
#   #   # Should be set manually to "application/json" for json data_format
#   #   Content-Type = "text/plain; charset=utf-8"
```

The computer has the configured IP. However, I tried using netcat  "nc -lup 8080" on my server, and it doesn't receive anything. How can I make sure this HTTP output works properly? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can use following command to get test metrics from telegraf

```
telegraf -debug -config path_to_config_file
```